# react native listview display toprow behind the navigatorIOS

Tags: react-native

i'm using reactnative 0.26 with navigatorIos and listview but the first row is hidden behind navigatorIOS. Just wondering if anyone has seen this problem. but works well with  fake data.

**screenshot**

[image]

Comment: can you share your styling applied ?

Comment: thanks was able to figure out that i needed to set the marginTop of the listview so that it would display it correctly. :) thanks!